# Not able to load bootstrap modal with ajax data

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter to create my website. I have a dropdown menu in my first page that contains links like 'Profile', 'Edit' etc. When i click on the link (profile) it should display the bootstrap modal with corresponding user data.  Used jquery to get the current id and ajax to retrieve data from database. But, when i tried to load the bootstrap modal with the response data, it displays nothing. What should i do to load the modal with ajax response data.? The response is an array containing user name, address, phone number etc.

Comment: can you post your coding?

Comment: I hope the problem with loading JS files. First load jqery.min.js then load bootstrap.min.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modal HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="MyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="UserName"></div>
                <div id="Address"></div>
                <div id="Phone"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" id="buttons-box">
                <button type="button" class="btn default" data-dismiss="modal">Close Modal</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

your jQuery script

```
$.get('your_server_script.php', {UserId: 'UserId'}, function (response) {
    $('#UserName').text(response.UserName);
    $('#Address').text(response.Address);
    $('#Phone').text(response.Phone);

    $('#MyModal').modal('show');
});
```